# How to make a guess in a list of random.sample?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I even provided the answer for myself and copy it, but it shows error. This is what I have so far.

```
hobbies = ['basketball', 'piano', 'swimming', 'badminton', 'photography', 'gamer']

my_child = random.sample(career_path, k=1)
my_child += random.sample(hobbies, k=1)
```

Comment: name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"{name}'s career and hobby are {my_child}")

secret_word = my_child
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
guess = ''
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input(f"Guess the hobby of {name}: ").lower()
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You won!")
        break
else:
    print("You guessed wrong!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a working example, I created some sample data for the career_path list. The missing piece was the if statement, where you must take the 1.st element of secret_word like this:

```
if guess == secret_word[1]:
```

And the complete code is then:

```
import random

career_path = ["doctor", "teacher", "author", "researcher", "athlete", "artist"]
hobbies = ["basketball", "piano", "swimming", "badminton", "photography", "gamer"]

my_child = random.sample(career_path, k=1)
my_child += random.sample(hobbies, k=1)

name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print(f"{name}'s career and hobby are {my_child}")
secret_word = my_child
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
guess = ""
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input(f"Guess the hobby of {name}: ").lower()
    guess_count += 1
    if guess == secret_word[1]:
        print("You won!")
        break
    else:
        print("You guessed wrong!")
```

Note that instead of

```
random.sample(career_path, k=1)
```

You could also have used random.choice():

```
random.choice(career_path)
```

As they will do the same.

Comment: I hope you found it useful. You can accept it as the correct answer if you like.